# DynamoDB table with mobileHub

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use dynamoDB with MobileHub and after I created a table in the MobileHub, I go to DynamoDB page and there I add items to my table. but for some reason when I go back to the MobileHub I see that there are 0 items.

Do I need to create the items in the MobileHub somewhere?
and if so where can .I add the Items?
or maybe is it that something in the dynamoDB is not enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Mobile Hub's web portal uses the Amazon DynamoDB's describe-table API, which can take up to 6 hours to update results, so you may see zero for some time before the counts update. You should see your table contents if you download and run the Demo App on Mobile Hub's "Integrate" page and use the NoSQL demo activity / view controller.